# Why does START TRANSACTION doesn't affect on autocommit implicitly as it should

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, autocommit

So this is from the docs:

> To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of
>   statements, use the `START TRANSACTION` statement:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

So from my understanding, unlike using `BEGIN`; command which shouldn't set autocommit to 0, `START TRANSACTION` should set it to 0.

Now if I do this (after I start a transaction):

```
select @@autocommit;
```

I get the value of 1.

Why autocommit is still enabled even if I use `START TRANSACTION` command? I thought that the `autocommit` variable is local to a single session. Or maybe even if it says 1, it is actually set to 0 within a transaction but just can't get that info by running a `SELECT @@autocommit;` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html says:

> With `START TRANSACTION`, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state.

The value of the autocommit variable is where MySQL stores the "previous state" so that it can revert to it after your transaction completes.

You can experimentally confirm that this behavior is followed. Make a change in a transaction, and then roll back the transaction.

```
CREATE TABLE test.MyTable (mycolumn TEXT);

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test.MyTable (mycolumn) VALUES ('Thing 1');
ROLLBACK;

SELECT * FROM test.MyTable; -- finds the row is gone
```

Notice that the change you did is rolled back. If autocommit had been in effect, then rollback would never work, because each statement would commit as soon as it is executed.

Comment: Yeah, this make sense. I thought that autocommit variable has different role. But as you said, rollback wouldn't be able if autocommit was set to 1. Will award bounty when 20  hours cooldown period passes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that `@@autocommit` is irrelevant.  The engine knows that it is in a transaction (`START` or `BEGIN`), so it ignores the setting of `autocommit`.  Instead it hangs onto changes until `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`).

Or do you have some reason to believe that the value of `autocommit` is relevant?  (Aside from `SELECT @@autocommit`.)

Comment: I wasn't really aware of what is the role of autocommit variable. I though it will be updated per session by doing something like `Start transaction` and changed to its previous value when changes are committed.

Comment: Bill says it better than I.